# Iframe is not working sometimes in Firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, iframe

I have an `iframe` with `style="display:none"` attribute. It works great all the time in chrome but causing an issue in Firefox sometimes. No `iframe` page is shown in Firefox and it is completely random.

Here is my function in `angularjs`, it invokes by clicking a button.

```
$scope.onAddGuarantorClicked = function() {
    if($("#frmGuarantor").length > 0) {
        $("#frmGuarantor" ).remove();
    }               

    $("#loadingIframe").show(); 

    var html="<div><iframe id='frmGuarantor' src='https://someUrl' width='100%' height='100%' onload='renderDone();' frameborder='0' style='display:none'></iframe></div>";               
    $("#dvAddGuarantor").append(html);
    $("#dvAddGuarantor").css("min-height", $("#dvSummary").height());
    $("#frmGuarantor").height($("#dvSummary").height() - 60);
    $("#frmGuarantor").attr("src","aDemoPage?id="+$scope.applicationId);
    $("#dvSummary").hide('slow');
    $("#dvAddGuarantor").show('slow');
};
```

And

```
window.renderDone = function(){
  var d = new Date(); // for now
  console.log('renderDone called outside at: H:'+ d.getHours()+' M:'+d.getMinutes()+' S:'+ d.getSeconds());

  $("#frmGuarantor").show();
  $("#loadingIframe").hide();              
};
```

In the console window, I found a warning while the `iframe` is not working. It says:

> jQuery.Deferred exception: divStyle is null computeStyleTests@...

[Here](https://pastebin.com/V7iRvxGD) is the complete warning messege.

I have then searched for the issue and found, [this](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/issues/3514) bug.

Is there any way to make the `iframe` work with `display:none` in Firefox?

Comment: `No iframe page is shown in firefox` - this isn't surprising, since style has `display:none`

Comment: Later in `renderDone()` I have $('#frmGuarantor').show(); Updated the question.

Comment: `I have then searched for the issue and found, this bug.` you're right, there is a bug ... but it's in Chrome (Firefox and Edge behave according to the CSS draft spec discussion that is linked to within that "bug", only Chrome doesn't follow the specification)

Comment: can you change `display:none` to `visbility:hidden` instead? not sure if jQuery.show() will show it, but then you can always `$("#frmGuarantor")[0].style.visibility='visible';` instead

Comment: or `$("#frmGuarantor").css('visibility', 'visible');` or even `$("#frmGuarantor").css('visibility', '');`

Comment: @JaromandaX, thank you man, the trick works! I should have thought this way.

Comment: Note that FF bug seems to have been fixed in v62. https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1467722

Answer (score 0):

There is a  [BUG](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/issues/3514) and therefore, firefox does not support `display:none` in `iframe`. To solve the issue, I have used

```
visbility:hidden
```

and to show the `iframe` used

```
$("#frmGuarantor")[0].style.visibility='visible'
```

Answer (score -3):

Try this:

```
$('#frmGuarantor').css("display", "inline-block");
```

instead of:

```
$('#frmGuarantor').show();
```